# asp.net mvc 3 variable length editable list

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-mvc-3

Following [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) post and the other posts that it links to, I have successfully built a page with a variable legnth editable list.

Now, I need to do another page with similar functionality, but going a step further. Basically I need to create a variable length list of objects as I have already done, but in this case each object in the list needs to have its own variable length editable sub list.

I can build the view with no problem but I guess I am lost as to how I will handle this in my POST controller method to save the objects.

Will my controller take 2 IEnumerable parameters?
I.E.

```
public ActionResult SaveList(IEnumerable<MainList>, IEnumerable<Sublist>)
{

}
```

It seems like this would work but I have no way of associatiing the objects in the sublist collection with the appropriate object in the main list collection.

What am I missing?

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, your sublists should be members of your `MainList` elements. In your view you will have a nested `foreach` loop to work with the `Sublist` elements. In the controller you just accept the `MainList` as a parameter (it should already have the sublists as members). Have you tried this approach? Is there something that doesn't work?

Comment: I need to give that approach another try, I had tried it in the past without succes, but I may have missed something. You are correct, the sublists are members of the mainlist objects. If I can get this to work, it would makes this pretty simple

Comment: @Yakimych , unfortunately this method is not working for me...the Sublist collection is empty

Comment: @stephen776 - can you take a look at the source html of your page and check the `name` attribute for your list elements and your sublist elements. That could give a clue why the ModelBinder is not picking them up. My guess is you are using partials and passing models into those partials, so the generated names include only the properties inside the sublist item, while it should contain the property of the main list first.

Comment: @Yakimych that worked. Had to make sure the name property assigned to the list elements matched up properly. Post it as an answer and the checkmark is yours. Thank you.

Comment: @stephen776 - Glad I could help. I summed up the results of the comment discussion as an answer, but since I haven't seen any of your actual code, it's mostly text and might be vague for someone who has the same problem as you. It could be helpful if you edited in the solution you've achieved (with a code sample) into your question for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summing up the results of our comment-discussions as an answer:

The sublists should be members of your `MainList` elements. In the View you will have a nested foreach loop to work with the `Sublist` elements. In the controller you just accept the `MainList` as a parameter (it should already have the sublists as members). In order for the `ModelBinder` to pick up the sublists correctly, the names of the inputs should include the names of main list first (and not just the properties inside the sublist item).

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to build a ModelBinder class to accept these parameters the way you want into your controller object.

Comment: I will have to look into this some more